# Saving multiple categories with one item

Tags: php, sql, database-design

I'm building a website where you add items with multiple categories.

what is the best way to store multiple categories in one field and still keep the field searchable?

Comment: The best way is to have separate fields for each category and then you must have a table which will store the reference between your item and categories

Comment: Bit more Explanation is Required

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't store multiple categories in one field, you create a separate table to assign categories to each item.  Similar to this:

```
-- create your table to store items/products
create table items
(
  id int,  -- this will be the PK
  name varchar(10)
);

insert into items values
(1, 'product1'),
(2, 'product2');

-- create your table to store categories
create table categories
(
  id int,  -- this will be the PK
  name varchar(50)
);

insert into categories values
(1, 'color'),
(3, 'material'),
(6, 'size');

-- create your join table to assign the categories to each item
-- this table will have a foreign key relationship to the items and categories table
create table items_categories
(
  item_id int,   -- both fields will be the PK
  category_id int
);

insert into items_categories values
(1,  1),
(2,  3),
(2,  6);
```

Then you will query the data by joining the tables:

```
select i.id itemid,
  i.name item,
  c.name category
from items i
left join items_categories ic
  on i.id = ic.item_id
left join categories c
  on ic.category_id = c.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4fc5/2)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is **not** to "store multiple categories in one field".

Instead, have a separate table for ItemCategories.

Read up about [Database Normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and inwardly digest.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a relationship table like `item-category` which simply stores the category id and the item id. Then you can directly put your search queries on the relationship table. Make sure it has its own primary key as well.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to store all categories in one filed, this is what "relation tables" are for, you should build table like:

```
product_categories (
    `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `category_id` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY (`product_id`, `category_id`)
)
```

This way you can also add [`FOREIGN KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) which will take care of changes, deletions and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Storing separate items in a single entry is rarely a good idea.

However, if you really insist on that, then probably best is to serialize the categories which you probably have stored as an array, for example using `json_serialize`. Then search the database using sqls `LIKE` operator.